# How can i open configure settings in vscode extensions development?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How to call the configure settings page when develop vscode extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need this command:

```sh
vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.openSettings')
```

Reference:

- [programmatically-executing-a-command](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command#programmatically-executing-a-command)
- [simple-commands](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands#simple-commands)